# Unable to update a variable(data frame) from inside a function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function

I am trying to write a python code which involves data frames as variables.
I have created an empty data frame(created_df) outside a function and assigned the columns to it. On a certain condition when the function runs it needs to update the data frame(created_df). The function runs fine on calling but it fails to update the data frame.
Please help me sort out this problem.

The structure of the code I have written is as follows

```
dir_path = "#path of directory "
dfs_dict = {}
created_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=[column names])

def create_latest():
   dfs_dict.clear()
   folders = [f for f in os.listdir(dir_path) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(dir_path, f))]
   for folder in folders:
      dfs_dict[folder] = transform(folder)
      #transform function returns a dataframe
   df = pd.concat(dfs_dict.values(), axis=1)# keys=dfs_dict.keys())
   created_df = df

def run():
  if created_df.empty:  
     create_latest()

run()
```

but when I call the `run()` it fails to update the created_df. I can not understand the reason behind it.

Comment: The variable must be declared as `global`.

Answer (score 0):

Python variables are scoped, that `created_df` outside of the function in the top-level of the script is in the global namespace, it is known by all scopes.

Inside a function (i.e. `create_latest`), names defined in the block are only known to other variables inside the same namespace.

You reassigned `created_df` inside the function `create_latest`, you only override the `created_df` inside the local namespace, and you don't modify the `created_df` in the global namespace.

If you want a function make a reassignment global, add a `global name` before the modification, like so:

```
def create_latest():
    ...
    global created_df
    created_df = pd.concat(dfs_dict.values(), axis=1, keys=dfs_dict.keys())
```

But this is bad behavior, you should let the function `return name` instead.

Like so:

```
def create_latest():
    ...
    return pd.concat(dfs_dict.values(), axis=1, keys=dfs_dict.keys())
...
if created_df.empty:  
    created_df = create_latest()
...
```

Comment: ...
if created_df.empty:  
    created_df = create_latest()
...
This block will also be in a function, how will it update the global variable this time?

Comment: @MONEET I didn't indent the last twi lines, it means I moved the last two lines outside of functions. You should do the same. Really, you shouldn't put them inside a function to update global variables. Rather you should call the functions and create the variables inside the global namespace.